# When i can access to SDL_Rendrerer after maximizing window?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I try to redraw window only when is need, but when window is resize in a hop (for example maximize), SDL_Renderer is not usable in new size some time after action.

Here is my simple example code:

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

bool redraw = true;

void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Rect& rect)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 50, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 90, 90, 90, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0, 0, rect.w, rect.h);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    redraw = false;
}

SDL_Rect resize(const SDL_Event& event)
{
    int win_w = (int) event.window.data1;
    int win_h = (int) event.window.data2;

    SDL_Rect rect = {0, 0, win_w, win_h};
    redraw = true;
    return rect;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Maximize test",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              800, 450, 0);
    SDL_SetWindowResizable(window, SDL_TRUE);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
            window, -1,
            SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Rect rect = {0, 0, 800, 450};

    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
                case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
                    switch (event.window.event) {
                        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
                            rect = resize(event);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (redraw) {
                draw(renderer, rect);
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    return 0;
}
```

At first, I try to get new renderer size `SDL_GetRendererOutputSize` in same result like getting size from event.

When I try to resize window with typical mouse motion actions, it works fine. But maximize or window manager resizing to one screen side does not work.

I try to use different event like `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED`, but with same result.

And yes, normally, I checks all SDL calls, with `SDL_RenderDrawLine` but without any errors.

Comment: You should draw each time you receive `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` window event, regardless if it is a resize, restore from minimized, or window overshadowing.

Comment: I was try to do it, but this not work. At this moment i have some small hack-fix, that i create own new SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED after resizing, and push it to events queue, which work for now.